# Issue using sprite, extra margin in character sprite

Tags: html, game-development, phaser-framework

when i load player character in Phaser.js using matter physics there's a extra margin. Is there a way to remove it using Phaser.js or i will need to update the image directly.

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you just want to change the size, because of physics collisions, you can simply use the function `setSize` of the `Body` object. *([link to the documentation](https://photonstorm.github.io/phaser3-docs/Phaser.Physics.Arcade.Body.html#setSize__anchor))*

***And*** with `setOffset` you can move the collision box, to the correct position.
*([link to the documentation](https://photonstorm.github.io/phaser3-docs/Phaser.Physics.Arcade.Body.html#setOffset__anchor))*

```
player.body.setSize(10,10); 
player.body.setOffset(5, 0);
```

> *[Here](https://phaser.io/examples/v3/view/physics/arcade/larger-bounding-box) you can find an official example with a static body, where the collision box is been made larger, with the same function.*

Comment: well, reading that links looks like this methods only works for arcade, i'm using matter and the properties of my player object is position, mass, gameObject and velocity. i used the position.y to push the sprite to the ground but what i want is to clip(decrease) the hit box.

Comment: @MatheusSantosAraújo Well you can to this for matterjs, but you would need a different function _(like `setBody({width:10, height:10})`, or `setRectangle` or ...)_. Since you didn't mentioned which engine you are using I had to assume, the default/ the most widely used engine. nevertheless here is the documentation for the mentioned function _([link to the documenntation](https://photonstorm.github.io/phaser3-docs/Phaser.Physics.Matter.Components.SetBody.html#setBody__anchor))_.

Comment: Thanks, using `setBody` works for me, i created an answer to help future folks

Answer (score 0):

**thanks to winner_joiner, for the help**

### For Arcade phisics

To crop the hit box of a sprite you can use the `player.body.setSize(10,10);` or `player.body.setOffset(5, 0);`

### For Matter phisics

Use `setBody({width:10, height:10})`, or `setRectangle`

### Final result

using `setBody({width:10, height:10})`
[image]